# Html.LabelFor not working?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, lambda, label

I have built a extention for the LabelFor that looks like this :

```
public static MvcHtmlString LabelFor<TModel, TValue>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> self, Expression<Func<TModel, TValue>> expression, Boolean showToolTip, string sufix = "")
{
    string description = string.Empty;
    var metadata = ModelMetadata.FromLambdaExpression(expression, self.ViewData);

    if (showToolTip)
        description = metadata.Description;

    return LabelFor(metadata.DisplayName, description, self.ViewContext.ViewData.TemplateInfo.GetFullHtmlFieldId(ExpressionHelper.GetExpressionText(expression)), sufix: sufix);
}
```

This is used like this :

```
<%: Html.LabelFor(model => model.ModelViewAd.TypeOfAd, false)%>
```

The Property do have the Display attribute like this :

```
[Display(Name = "Type of ad", Description = "")]
```

With a breakpoint I can see that the metadata.DisplayName is set to null?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem when away without any changes after a couple of cleans and rebuilds. So the code is correct.

Answer (score 2):

Decorate your property with this attribute instead:

`[DisplayName("Type of ad")]`